# How can I extract Stackoverflow post titles in Perl?

Tags: bash, perl

I want to write a BASH script (using sed, grep, awk etc) to extract the titles of the questions from the https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month.

For example:

- Which is faster: while(1) or while(2)?
- Replacing a 32-bit loop count variable with 64-bit introduces crazy performance deviations

Comment: I suggest to use: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/month

Comment: Title says Perl, tag and question says Bash, then you mention sed, grep, awk... which is it?

Comment: I'd like to answer this question. I don't think it's unclear at all and I've have code to ad.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a small [Mojo::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent) program that fetches the page, finds the right `A` tags with a selector, and extracts the text of those tags:

```
use v5.10;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $tx = $ua->get( 'https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month' );
unless( $tx->success ) {
    die "Something wrong happened, so handle that";
    }

say $tx->res->dom('a.question-hyperlink')->map( 'text' )->join( "\n" );
```

The [ojo](http://www.metacpan.org/module/ojo) module, which also comes with [Mojolicious](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious), has one-liner shortcuts for the command line:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'say g(shift)->dom("a.question-hyperlink")->map("text")->join("\n")' 'stackoverflow.com/?tab=month'
```

As the comments noted, instead of scraping the HTML, there's an XML version at https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/month. You could grab that and select things with XPath.

Comment: That one-liner is sweet, but I think it requires a bit of explanation for what is it actually doing.  i.e. what does `g(shift)` mean?

Comment: `g(shift)` means perform a GET request on the url you pass into your one-liner.